# Compare a list with the rows in pandas using Cosine similarity and get the rank

Tags: python, python-3.x, cosine-similarity

I have a Pandas Dataframe and a user input , i would require to compare the user input with each of the rows in the dataframe and get the Ranked list of rows in the dataframe based on Cosine Similarties.

```
Department  Country Age Grade   Score
Math    India   Young   A   97
Math    India   Young   B   86
Math    India   Young   D   68
Science India   Young   A   92
Science India   Young   B   81
Science India   Young   C   76
Social  India   Young   B   88
Social  India   Young   D   62
Social  India   Young   C   72
```

User input :

```
Country Age Grade   Score
India   Young   B   84
India   Young   D   65
India   Young   A   98
```

I would prefer to consider all the rows of the dataframe as lists,
and consider the User input as list. 
Say `User_list1 = ['India','Young','B','84']`and compare it using Cosine Similarlity with each rows of the dataframe (considering them as a list) and get the Ranked output of `Department`.

In my case, the output will be the Ranked list of `Department :
Out = ['Math','Science','Social']` : This should based on Cosine Similarity results.

Comment: You have categorical features. How are you going to encode it ? Mention your encoded dataframe.

Comment: Hi Abdur, that's how my problem is..I m new to python..so getting to know things slowly

Comment: Friends, Any suggestions..or help on this pls

Comment: Do you know how to solve it manually ? If yes, then just give a hand-solve example. So I can proceed but If no, then you have to first learn instead of posting this on Stackoverflow because this platform is for resolving programming issues.

Comment: @AbdurRehman, thanks for showing the interest to help me. I will let you know what to be done manually.

Comment: Lets compare the first input list : [ India, Young, A, 98 ] with all the rows in df and give the ranking to each Department based on Closest Match. So it will be Math = 1, Science = 2, Social = 3. ( Math has A with score 97 which is closest to input score 98. Science comes second, Since Social has no A it comes last )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both of dataframes as above,

```
df
   Department Country Age Grade Score
0   Math    India   Young   A   97
1   Math    India   Young   B   86
2   Math    India   Young   D   68
3   Science India   Young   A   92
4   Science India   Young   B   81
5   Science India   Young   C   76
6   Social  India   Young   B   88
7   Social  India   Young   D   62
8   Social  India   Young   C   72

input

Country Age Grade   Score
0   India   Young   B   84
1   India   Young   D   65
2   India   Young   A   98
```

One of possible solution is,

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict
import sys
```

Convert categorical features to numeric using `scikit-learn` package,

```
df['Country'] = le.fit_transform(df['Country'])
df['Age'] = le.fit_transform(df['Age'])
df['Grade'] = le.fit_transform(df['Grade'])
df
```

Output:

```
Department Country Age Grade    Score
0       Math    0      0    0   97
1       Math    0      0    1   86
2       Math    0      0    3   68
3      Science  0      0    0   92
4      Science  0      0    1   81
5      Science  0      0    2   76
6      Social   0      0    1   88
7      Social   0      0    3   62
8      Social   0      0    2   72

input['Country'] = le.fit_transform(input['Country'])
input['Age'] = le.fit_transform(input['Age'])
input['Grade'] = le.fit_transform(input['Grade'])
input
```

Output:

```
 Country  Age   Grade  Score
0   0       0     1     84
1   0       0     2     65
2   0       0     0     98
```

Define a `cosine-similarity` function,

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
    nom = np.sum(np.multiply(a, b))
    denom = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a))) * np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(b)))
    sim = nom / denom
    return sim

dept = list(df['Department'].values)
dept = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(dept).keys())
results = []
for i in range(len(input)):
    similarity = []
    for j in range(len(df)):
        a = input.iloc[i] 
        b = df.iloc[j, 1:]
        c_sim = cosine_similarity(a, b)
        similarity.append(c_sim)

    max_similarity = []
    for k in range(0, len(df), 3):
        max_3 = max(similarity[k:k+3])
        max_similarity.append(max_3)

    max_idx = max_similarity.index(max(max_similarity))
    results.append(dept[max_idx])
results
```

Output:

```
['Math', 'Social', 'Math']
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation and solution. I am checking it now, few mins i will revert

Comment: i am accepting the answer its good.  But i would require only 3 records in a list, not a list of 3. Should be [ Math, Science, Social ] - Watever the Top 3 records only pls. Really really appreciate your answer and help.

Comment: @pyds_learner so you want only one `department` whatever the top will be for one input? Is this what you want ? In other words, there will be 3 departments(top) for 3 input records ?

Comment: Yes Basically i wanted only the Top 3 for all the given input records. We can select the Top 3 from your results that should also be fine.

Comment: So in this case, results would be `['Math', 'Social', 'Math']` ?. Update me so I can update the reply soon.

Comment: @pyds_learner here you go! Up-vote if your reputation allows you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abdur...upvoting is not happening