# How to compute the cosine similarity between different subcategories in one column in pandas/sklearn? (Knowledge based recommendation)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a program that recommends skincare products based on user input.

**Desired result:**

I would like to iterate through each subcategory under the column data['category'] and return the product name (data['name']) of the one with the highest score. I'm sure the solution is relatively simple, but I'm very new to pandas and have been working at it for a couple of days.

**Issues:**

Currently, when I return the data after running the recommender function ( this line `print(data['name'].iloc[indices]`) it only returns items from the subcategory 'cleansers'. Ideally, it would return all products with the highest similarity, but even when I edit this line `score = score[0:15]` to display all results, it only displays cleansers. This could be an issue with how I'm computing the similarity

**Possible Solution:**

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033724/compare-a-list-with-the-rows-in-pandas-using-cosine-similarity-and-get-the-rank) solution is super close to what I want. However, I can't seem to figure out how to implement it with my program.  Running the input through cosine_similarity the way that example does, returns an error 'You need to rehape using a.reshape(-1, 1)' but reshaping the input also doesn't work because it s a string list.

I guess I'm asking, how do I achieve my desired result. Is that ^ solution close? Am I way off base?

Also here is my csv file if you'd like to run it yourself to test outcomes (don't worry, its very very small condensed version) https://pastebin.com/5iz8nxat

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from ast import literal_eval
    from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

    data = pd.read_csv('skin_recs.csv')
    data = data[['category','skin_types','concern','sensitive','name','details']]

    data['skin_types'] = data['skin_types'].fillna('[]')
    data['concern'] = data['concern'].fillna('[]')
    #convert to python dict
    data['skin_types'] = data['skin_types'].apply(literal_eval)
    data['concern'] = data['concern'].apply(literal_eval)
    #grab all skin types & concerns
    data['skin_types'] = data['skin_types'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'].lower() for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [])
    data['concern'] = data['concern'].apply(lambda x: [i['name'].lower() for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [])
    #remove spaces
    data['skin_types'] = data['skin_types'].apply(lambda x: [i.replace(' ', '') for i in x])
    data['concern'] = data['concern'].apply(lambda x: [i.replace(' ', '') for i in x])

    s = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['skin_types']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
    s.name = 'type'
    data = data.drop('skin_types', axis=1).join(s)
    s = data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['concern']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
    s.name = 'goal'
    data = data.drop('concern', axis=1).join(s)

    data['metadata'] = data.apply(lambda x : ''.join(x['type']) + ', ' + ''.join(x['goal']), axis = 1)

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    vect_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['name'])
    similarity = cosine_similarity(vect_matrix, vect_matrix)
    mapping = pd.Series(data.index,index = data['metadata'])

    def recommender(input, category):
        index = mapping[input]
        score = list(enumerate(similarity[index]))
        score = sorted(score, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
        score = score[0:15]
        indices = [i[0] for i in score]
        print(data['name'].iloc[indices])
    recommender('dry, acne', 'cleanser')
```

Comment: You need to search for recommendation engines/systems. Most similar or collaborative filtering should do.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov collaborative filtering won't work for my case.This is an implementation of knowledge based recommendations.